# c ++ typedef std::function<> How to use?

Tags: c++

Hi I am working on this project and in the header the file the following is defined

```
typedef std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)> HashFunction;
```

How exactly do i use this with my HashFunction? 
When I try

```
HashFunction myHashFunction;
myHashFunction("mystring");
```

the program crashes.

Comment: It would probably help immensely if that function object were actually referencing *a function*. [See the documentation on `std::function<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), or any other standard library class, before you start trying to use them.

Answer (score 21):

An object of type `std::function<Signature>` behaves pretty much like a function pointer pointing to a function with the signature `Signature`. A default constructed `std::function<Signature>` just doesn't point at any function, yet. The key difference between `std::function<Signature>` and a function pointer `Signature*` is that you can have some state in form of a function object in `std::function<Signature>`.

To use an object of this type you'll need to initialize it with a suitable function, e.g.

```
#include <functional>
typedef std::function<unsigned int(const std::string&)> HashFunction;

struct Hash {
    unsigned int operator()(std::string const& s) const {
        return 0; // this is a pretty bad hash! a better implementation goes here
    }
};

int main() {
    HashFunction hash{ Hash() };
    hash("hello");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When I use `HashFunction hash{ Hash() };` It gives me an error saying that ; is expected after hash

Comment: @user2407736: At least the use is meant to go into fuction. I'll update the example to be a complete program.

Comment: Rolled back the extra `;`, which did not belong there and stopped the program from compiling.